# Run Perl script from PHP to create new directory on server

Tags: php, perl, apache

I'm trying to have PHP run a Perl script on my apache web server, but not exactly sure where to start. I looked around on here and other websites and this is what I come up with. Here's my index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['button']))
{
  exec('/usr/bin/perl /home/gpham/scripts/test.pl');
}
?>

<html>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <button name="button">Run Perl</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my Perl file test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $cmd = "mkdir /home/gpham/testfolder";
system($cmd);
```

So basically, what I want is when the user click on the "Run Perl" button, it will create that new folder on the web server. But it isn't working. When I click on the button, nothing happens. Can anyone pinpoint what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: why would you not just create the dir with php?? using one language to call a script in another language to do what the first language can do seems pointless.

Comment: Especially when the second language is only used as a very thin wrapper for a system command.

Answer (score 2):

You're taking an impressively roundabout path here. You're using PHP to call Perl to run a shell command; you could just as well call the `mkdir` command from PHP directly using [PHP `shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec), or skip the shell command entirely and call [Perl `mkdir()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) or [PHP `mkdir()`](http://php.net/mkdir) directly.

But that all aside, the most likely issue here is that the web server doesn't have permissions to write to the parent directory (`/home/gpham`). Since this is your home directory, this state of affairs is proper. Create the directory from outside PHP and set its permissions appropriately, or choose another location for it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just want to give you a hug right now. It's working. This is my first time using PHP and Perl so I wrote all that long code. If you haven't pointed it out, I'm gonna be going around in circle for much longer.

Comment: I still have another problem though. I know I'm going in circle but I just want to test calling the perl script from php. If I used mkdir it worked fine, but if I put the mkdir command in the perl script and use shell_exec to call the script, it wouldn't work. I set the file permission to 777 and turned off the safe mode also.